# XML integer element with leading zeros

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML file with an element that is of integer type but it has leading zeros. Before I send the XML off I can see in the xml file that the integer is e.g. 001234 ...but when getting processed as it's meant to be an integer the leading zeros are removed.

Is there a way in the xml or xsd to specify that this integer is always 6 characters in length? (Before I tell at the people who are receiving the xml to change type to convert at their end)

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declaring the type as xs:integer is telling everyone that leading zeros are not significant, i.e. that 0012 and 12 are interchangeable and equivalent, because that is part of what it means to be an integer. You can use a pattern facet to restrict the length to 6 digits, but you will get yourself into a mess, because for example if you do an identity transform through a schema-aware processor then the leading zeros are likely to be lost.

If leading zeroes really are significant (as in a phone number, for example), then it shouldn't be typed as an integer, but as a string matching the pattern \d+.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you should be able to use the [decimal](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal) type in your schema.

Comment: Not helpful. Integer is a subtype of decimal, so making it decimal doesn't give you anything that you can't do with an integer.